# /opt insufficient permissions

Tags: macos, permission, macports, xquartz

After updating Mountain Lion to Mavericks xQuartz and MacPorts throws errors about insufficient permissions. (xQuartz and MacPorts are the latest version)

I noticed:

```
$ sudo mkdir /opt/tmp
mkdir: /opt/tmp: Permission denied
```

I am on Administrator Account.

```
sudo port install htop
Error: Insufficient privileges to write to MacPorts install prefix.
```

I can't even uninstall MacPorts with the command from [here](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html)

```
%% sudo rm -rf \
/opt/local \
/Applications/DarwinPorts \
/Applications/MacPorts \
/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
/Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
/Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
/Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
/Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
/Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
~/.macports
```

Comment: What do `ls -l /opt' and  `ls -l /opt/local' show. And did you follow the macports OS upgrade instructions

Comment: drwxr-xr-x@
Yes, I followed them.

Comment: And the user and groups i.e. the full output and for both directories

Comment: drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel   102 25 Okt 17:12 opt

drwxr-xr-x   11 root  admin   374 27 Okt 14:26 local

Comment: See the duplicate, where I added another possible reason for this (one that happened to me).