# Issue installing MacPorts on Mavericks

Tags: macos, permission, macports, sudo

I try to install MacPorts and get this

```
$ sudo make install
make: getcwd: Permission denied
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
===> making install in doc
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
make: getcwd: Permission denied
/usr/bin/install -c -d -o root -g admin -m 0755 "/opt/local"
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
install: mkdir /opt: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install] Error 71
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I am also not able to

```
$ sudo mkdir /opt
mkdir: /opt: Permission denied
```

I can create the directory with

```
open /
```

and then with Finder.

I am also able to install MacPorts with the installer .pgk, but then:

```
sudo port install htop
Error: Insufficient privileges to write to MacPorts install prefix.
```

Comment: It seems that MacPorts has issues with Mavericks. See [this]( http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107092/opt-insufficient-permissions) question. Are you [migrating](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) or is this a new installation?

Comment: its a new installation, i compiled on mavericks.

Comment: Which guide did you follow? Have you installed Xcode or Xcode command line utilities?

Comment: [Guide](http://www.macports.org/install.php)

I have installed xcode 5.01 with command line utilities.
I think theres something wrong with permissions. as you can see in my original post, any ideas?

Comment: please provide the output of `ls -l /opt`. Did you try to uninstall everything(xcode+command line tools and macports) and then install it again? If you don't need macports specifically, I'd recommend [brew](http://brew.sh/). I know, it is not the perfect solution but I assuming it is a bug of MacPorts(seeing the rising questions from other users) and you are not able to do anything right now.

Comment: /opt does not exist. let us ignore macports for a moment.
i am even not able to do 'sudo mkdir /test'
'mkdir: /test: Permission denied'
i think something with the system is wrong.
output of "ls -la" of /
[/ output](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=A28ebaan)

Comment: Well, try the following: Reboot into single user mode, this is archieved by holding down alt(option) + s while rebooting. At the prompt `/sbin/fsck -fy`(careful, QWERTZ-Layout), after that type `/sbin/mount -wu`. Now `/bin/chmod 1775 /`. At last `/bin/sync`,then `exit`. This will check your filesystem integrity and correct permissions for your root directory.

Comment: Perfect, that solved the problem.
Now I'am able to install MacPorts as well. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, try the following:
Reboot into single user mode, this is archieved by holding down alt(option) + s while rebooting.
At the prompt `/sbin/fsck -fy`(careful, QWERTZ-Layout), after that type `/sbin/mount -wu`. Now `/bin/chmod 1775 /`. At last `/bin/sync`,then `exit`.

This will check your filesystem integrity and correct permissions for your root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check that root's UID is actually 0 on your system: `sudo id -u` should print 0.

This wasn't the case on my system after updating to Mavericks. If it isn't, you can do the following to fix it:

- boot into single user mode
- change to `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users`
- check that root's UID is wrong in `root.plist` using `plutil -p root.plist`
- if it is wrong, start by making a backup: `cp root.plist root.plist.orig`
- convert the plist to xml format using `plutil -fmt xml1 root.plist`
- use your favorite editor to change the number after `<key>uid</key>` to `0`
- convert the plist back to binary format using `plutil -fmt binary1 root.plist`

Answer (score 1):

The UID of root on your system was: 217 _krbtgt (Kerberos Ticket Granting Ticket)

> There IS a user called _krbtgt (Kerberos Ticket Granting Ticket) in
>   /System/Library/DirectoryServices/DefaultLocalDB/Default/users,
>   that indeed is user 217.

<sup>More information: https://discussions.apple.com/message/24414669#24414669</sup>